# How to aggregate based on the value of the header in apache camel?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, aggregate, expression

I have a camel aggregate correlation expression as below in spring dsl.

```
<correlationExpression>
 <simple>${header.Method}-${header.Type}</simple>
</correlationExpression>
```

I want to aggregate records based on the value of header.Type. e.g. I have three values in header.Type, that is GET, SET, and GO and header.Method is constant for all the three types.

I want to have GET and SET aggregated in one record but if header.Type is equals to GO then it should be aggregated separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple Choice in your route to consolidate the Header for aggregation.  This new header would then be your aggregation key:

In Java DSL:

```
    .choice()
      .when(header("Type").isEqualToIgnoreCase("GO"))
        .setHeader("AggId", constant("GO"))
        .otherwise()
          .setHeader("AggId", constant( "GET-SET"))
          .end()
    .aggregate(header("AggId"), new RecordAggregationStrategy())
```